# Limit size of a list in python

Tags: list, python-2.7

I want to limit the size of a list in python 2.7 I have been trying to do it with a while loop but it doesn't work

```
l=[]
i=raw_input()//this is the size of the list
count=0
while count<i:
    l.append(raw_input())
    count=count+1
```

The thing is that it does not finish the loop. I think this problem has an easy answer but I can't find it.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
i=raw_input()//this is the size of the list
```

`raw_input()` returns a string, not an integer, so comparisons between `i` and `count` don't make sense.  [In Python 3, you'd get the error message `TypeError: unorderable types: int() < str()`, which would have made things clear.]  If you convert `i` to an int, though:

```
i = int(raw_input())
```

it should do what you expect.  (We'll ignore error handling etc. and possibly converting what you're adding to `l` if you need to.)

Note though that it would be more Pythonic to write something like

```
for term_i in range(num_terms):
    s = raw_input()
    l.append(s)
```

Most of the time you shouldn't need to manually keep track of indices by "+1", so if you find yourself doing it there's probably a better way.

Answer (score 1):

That is because i has a string value type, and int < "string" always returns true.

What you want is:

```
l=[]
i=raw_input() #this is the size of the list
count=0
while count<int(i): #Cast to int
    l.append(raw_input())
    count=count+1
```

Comment: I think this and @DSM's answers are best for not suggesting to use `input()` with python2.7. Much better to take the raw input and try and convert to int. +1

Answer (score 0):

You should try changing your code to this:

```
l = []
i = input() //this is the size of the list
count = 0
while count < i:
    l.append(raw_input())
    count+=1
```

raw_input() returns a string while input() returns an integer. Also `count+=1` is better programming practice than `count = count + 1`. Good luck